# getpos(".") in visual mode equals getpos("v")

Tags: visual-mode, cursor

I use `neovim 0.3.1` only.
I define the following function and map to do a test for `getpos` in visual mode:

```
function! show_position()
  echo getpos("'<") getpos("'>") getpos(".") getpos("v") getcurpos()
endfunction
vmap ;j :<c-u>call show_position()<cr>gv
```

The test file contains (please ignore `:` and `|` for now)

```
0123456789
11234:56789
2123456789
3123456789
4123456789
51234|56789
6123456789
7123456789
```

I then enter visual mode using `v`, `V` or `<c-v>`, move around and then press `;j` to get the position of various markers. I have two cases tested (we can press `o` in visual mode to switch the case):

1. When `:` is the place I started the visual selection and `|` is the current cursor place,
2. When `|` is the place I started the visual selection and `:` is the current cursor place,

In both cases, the result shows that `getcurpos() == getpos(".") == getpos("v") == upper left corner of the selection`, which I feel contradicts with common sense as well as the doc `:h line`

> ```
>       .   the cursor position
>       $   the last line in the current buffer
>       'x  position of mark x (if the mark is not set, 0 is
>           returned)
>       v   In Visual mode: the start of the Visual area (the
>           cursor is the end).  When not in Visual mode
>           returns the cursor position.  Differs from |'<| in
>           that it's updated right away.
> ```

How to get the current cursor position in visual mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're having here is that by the time `show_position()` is running you're already *out* of visual mode, since the `:` switched to command-line mode before that function gets called.

If you call `getpos("v")` before you leave visual mode, it will correctly return where you actually started the visual selection, instead of the top of the selection (`'<`).

You can use a `vmap <expr> ...` to be able to evaluate the expressions before leaving visual mode. For example:

```
function! show_position()
  return ":\<c-u>echo 'start=" . string(getpos("v")) . " end=" . string(getpos(".")) . "'\<cr>gv"
endfunction
vmap <expr> ;j show_position()
```

When I start the visual selection on `:` and end it at `|`, `;j` tells me:

```
start=[0, 2, 6, 0] end=[0, 6, 6, 0]
```

On the other hand, starting at `|` and going up to `:` gives me:

```
start=[0, 6, 6, 0] end=[0, 2, 6, 0]
```

(Note: I'm on VIM 8.0, but I'd expect NeoVim would behave the same here.)

Comment: Thanks. This works very well. I just find for neovim, there is an more flexible choice which is to start the command by `<Cmd>` instead of using `<expr>`. Using `<expr>` has a lot of restrictions.